# RESTful design for create if absent use case

Tags: java, rest

GET request on /template/settings would return the default setting for an Organization entity. I have a use case where all the organizations will have default settings. The first time an organization tries to access GET /template/settings if there are no settings, we need to create settings and then return them. This is a side effect. What would be a better design for this case?

Templates is a new feature which we would be turned on for organizations we choose. That specific event of turning on the feature would require a POST and it would be a good RESTful design. Once all the existing organizations are turned on for Templates, any new organizations added to the system will not have this event. So I would need create-if-absent construct.

Would this be the case for redirect to itself for creation?

Comment: How do you know what the settings are when someone tries a GET for something that doesn't yet exist?

Comment: This should be handled on he client. Get, if 404, Post to create.

Comment: Or just simply Post to create if the client knows it has no settings. Get should be idempotent

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific. Templates is a new feature which we would turn on for organizations we choose. That specific event of turning on the feature would require a POST and it would be a good RESTful design. New organization on-boarding would not have this event. So is the need for create if absent.

Comment: you shold use URIs that points to a resource such as GET /template/settings/{settingId} for example  `GET /template/settings/default` (default as settingId) -> get the default setting.  `GET /template/settings/org1/` (org1 as settingId) -> that gets the setting of org1. Then, if not exists setting for org1 then you could use the default setting while org1's setting is created or you could use default as template to create org1 setting when 404 is returning calling `GET /template/settings/org1/`.

Comment: Then You should create a setting using the URI `POST /template/settings/`  and   you should update a existing setting using the URI `PUT /template/settings/org1/`.  (org1 as settingId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the following.

1. There will be one immutable resource representing the initial settings any new organization will get.
2. When a new organization GETs its settings, it will receive the representation of this resource.
3. When this organization PUTs or PATCHes an update to these settings, then a copy of the immutable resource is created for that particular organization and this copy is updated.
4. When the organization GETs its settings again, it will receive the representation of its own updated resource.